# Solr - Using the Result of a Raw Query Param Function in a Filter (fq)

Tags: solr, lucene, filtering, geospatial

I am trying to work with a function's results like the measure of distance.

I have a raw query param

```
distance=query({!func v='mul(geodist(store_location,45.98,-110.65),1.60934)'})
```

I know I can use it as a field by having it in the query string as

```
fl=*,distance:$distance
```

Is there an equivalent to using it in the fq param? Using it like

```
fq=$distance:[0 TO 100]
# or
fq=distance:[0 TO 100]
```

doesn't seem to work. Is there another syntax for accessing this custom value of the document and filtering on it? The overall goal is to filter out results past a certain mileage range. Then I should be able to get a count of all the docs within the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [geofilt](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/spatial-search.html#geofilt) query parser, and get the computed `geodist()` in `fl` :

```
q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=store_location&pt=45.98,-110.65&d=160.934&fl=*,geodist()
```